# Adding a programatically created agent into a process model?

Tags: anylogic

On startup I programatically create two agents at particular points. Using the following code -

```
Officer off = this.add_officers();
off.setXY(this.start1.getX(), this.start1.getY());

Officer off2 = this.add_officers();
off2.setXY(this.start2.getX(), this.start2.getY());
```

I would like to add these two agents into my process model logic, however the following code does not produce the required behaviour -

```
pedSource.addAgentToContents(off);
pedSource.addAgentToContents(off2);
```

How can I add the programatically created agents into my process model?[image]

Answer (score 2):

instead of PedSource, use the ["Enter"](http://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/_ELR/Enter.html) object. and the in the code use:

```
enter.take(off)
enter.take(off2)
```

Comment: correct. A source object creates new agents whereas the "Enter" object takes existing objects and feeds them into the process chart. Also checkout the "Exit" object which can pass them pack using some Java message code in the "on exit" property of the block.